# Smooth hover out animation works on a random website but not on mine, why?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the inset border example [here](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/05/8-simple-css3-transitions-that-will-wow-your-users/) that should be smooth when the mouse hovers and go back to normal when the mouse goes away. The example on this page works perfectly on that page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <style type="text/css">
        body > div
        {
            margin:121px 149px;
            width:483px;
            height:298px;
            background:#676470;
            color:#fff;
            font-family:Lato;
            font-weight:900;
            font-size:3.4em;
            text-align:center;
            line-height:298px;
            transition:all 0.3s ease;
        }
        .border:hover
        {
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 25px #53a7ea;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="border">Inset Border</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

When I try implement that, my effect goes smoothly just when the mouse hovers. When the mouse leaves the div, it returns to normal abruptly.

This is the CSS I have applied to that div.

The element is a div. Every link that may exist on a row that is not the first one, should have the effect.

```
.newJobsTable {
  color:#666;
    font-size:1.0em;
  margin:0px auto;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding:40px;

}


. newJobsTable tr td:nth-child(1){
  text-align:left;
  width:30%;
  color:#000;
  font-weight:500;
  font-size: 0.72em;
  letter-spacing: 0.12em;
}

. newJobsTable tr:not(first-child) td {
  text-align:left;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-weight:100;
  color:#f00;
}


. newJobsTable tr:not(first-child) td a {
  all:unset;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

. newJobsTable tr:not(first-child) td a:hover {
  all:unset;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  background:#af0000;
  color:#fff;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
    font-weight: 200;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  padding-top:5px;
  transition:all 0.3s ease;
}
```

I cannot use Javascript for this, just exclusively CSS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed the function of the transition `ease` to `ease-in-out` makes start slow and finish slow at the time that you preset 0.3s

Comment: in my perspective it makes better.

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code, copy and paste into your editor and save. It should work. Hop this helps

```
        body>div {
            margin: 121px 149px;
            width: 483px;
            height: 298px;
            background: #676470;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: Lato;
            font-weight: 900;
            font-size: 3.4em;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 298px;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }

        .border:hover {
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 25px #53a7ea;
        }


        .newJobsTable {
            color: #666;
            font-size: 1.0em;
            margin: 0px auto;
            font-weight: 200;
            padding: 40px;

        }


        .newJobsTable tr td:nth-child(1) {
            text-align: left;
            width: 30%;
            color: #000;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-size: 0.72em;
            letter-spacing: 0.12em;
        }

        .newJobsTable tr:not(first-child) td {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 0.7em;
            font-weight: 100;
            color: #f00;
        }


        .newJobsTable tr:not(first-child) td a {
            all: unset;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
            padding-bottom: 1px;
            font-weight: 100;
        }

        .newJobsTable tr:not(first-child) td a:hover {
            all: unset;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
            padding-bottom: 3px;
            background: #af0000;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            font-weight: 200;
            border-radius: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="border">Inset Border</div>


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: May I ask what parts you changed ? You seem to have combined both of the code blocks he wrote ?

Answer (score 0):

correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't the transition property be in Element a? (not a:hover).  you couldn't have missed that, could you ?

```
.newJobsTable tr:not(first-child) td a {
  all:unset;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  font-weight: 100;
  transition: all 0.3s ease; //  is it defined here ?
}
```

if it doesn't work that way, you can download it as a js fiddle or code snippet.

Comment: for some reason, if I put that on the hover it gets worse.